# Using Goroost with Meteor js

Tags: meteor, push-notification

Has anyone successfully installed the push notification system Goroost (https://goroost.com/) with Meteor JS?

The Goroost files are in my public folder, and I am able to hit the essential files of /roost.html, /roost_worker.js, and /roost_manifest.json

I am hosting my site on meteor.com, which may be a factor. The link to my site is here: http://oc_connect.meteor.com/.

I can get the subscription notification and push notifications working in a Safari desktop browser, but not Safari mobile and not Chrome either desktop or mobile.

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work by installing Force SSL https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/force-ssl which has kick started Android notifications.

And GoRoost does not currently work with Safari mobile, just Safari desktop. So, the problem is solved.